# MySQL; Return most frequent occurrence(s) where there may be more than one

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with student ids (sID) and the classes (cCODE) that they're taking.

I'm trying to retrieve the student ids of the student(s) who are taking the highest number of classes, so the query needs to allow for the fact that there might be a tie.

I know the highest number of occurrences of the same sID will indicate the the one I'm looking for so If I was just looking to retrieve the top record I'd go

```
mysql> select sID, count(sID) as NumberOfClasses
-> from STUDENT_CLASSES
-> group by sID
-> order by NumberOfClasses desc
-> limit 1;
+------+-----------------+
| sID  | NumberOfClasses |
+------+-----------------+
| 2040 |               3 |
+------+-----------------+
```

I've tried

```
mysql> select sID, count(sID) as NumberOfClasses
-> from STUDENT_CLASSES
-> group by sID
-> having NumOfClasses=3;
+------+-----------------+
| sID  | NumberOfClasses |
+------+-----------------+
| 2040 |               3 |
| 3040 |               3 |
+------+-----------------+
```

Which works but only because I know the value of the highest number of projects anyone is working on is 3, what I need is some way of putting a MAX() function after the = that would calculate the highest value in the NumberOfProjects column of the newly created table….

Any thoughts?

This is the original STUDENT_CLASSES table…

```
mysql> select * from STUDENT_CLASSES;
+------+-------+
| sID  | cCODE | 
+------+-------+
| 2040 | C101  |
| 2040 | C102  |         
| 2040 | C103  | 
| 3282 | C101  | 
| 3282 | C102  | 
| 2113 | C105  | 
| 3040 | C102  | 
| 3040 | C105  | 
| 3040 | C108  | 
+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried combining the two approaches using a subquery?

```
select sID, count(sID) as NumberOfClasses
from STUDENT_CLASSES
group by sID
having count(sID) = (select count(sID) N from STUDENT_CLASSES group by sID order by N desc limit 1)
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked. I had tried to combine them using a subquery but I think I'd approached it in the wrong way using MAX in the subquery and trying to refer to something that wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain in MySQL with an aggregation query.  I would suggest just using variables

```
select sID, NumberOfClasses
from (select sID, count(sID) as NumberOfClasses,
             @max := if(count(sID) > @max, count(sID), @max) as unused
      from STUDENT_CLASSES cross join
           (select @max := -1) vars
      group by sID
     ) t
where NumberOfClasses = @max;
```

EDIT:

Okay, the correct and tested answer is:

```
select sID, NumberOfClasses
from (select t.*,
             @max := if(NumberOfClasses > @max, NumberOfClasses, @max) as unused
      from (select sID, count(sID) as NumberOfClasses
            from STUDENT_CLASSES cross join
                 (select @max := -1) vars
            group by sID
           ) t
     ) t
where NumberOfClasses = @max;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb5d8d/6).

In other words, the aggregation needs to be done first, and then the variable assignment.  This is for an arcane reason, involving the order of processing of aggregations.  If only MySQL supported window functions, this would be much easier, more standard, and compatible with other databases.

Comment: This looks like a neat way of doing it but I couldn't get it to work and it's a little above my level of understanding to figure out why. (This is technically my second day of teaching myself SQL!). At least I know how to declare variables in MySQL now! :)

Comment: @audiob4 . . . The `where` clause had `NumOfClasses` rather than `NumberOfClasses`.  Here is a SQL Fiddle showing it working:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb5d8d/2.

Comment: I should have spotted that. The code now returns sID 3202 with two classes instead of the desired result of sID 2040 & 3040 with three classes each. Is that to do with the (select @max :=-1) line?

Answer (score 0):

> select 
>       sID, 
>       count(cCODE) as NumberOfClasses
>   from
>       STUDENT_CLASSES 
>   group by 
>       sID 
>   having 
>       count(cCODE) = (
>           select max(C) 
>           from ( select count(cCODE) as C from STUDENT_CLASSES group by sID)
>       )